# Crear controles en tiempo de ejecucion C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

quisiera que me ayudaran con el siguiente problema: Creo un panel en tiempo de ejecución y dentro de este panel le agrego dos Label para crear esto uso el siguiente código.

```
//Creo el panel
        Panel nuevoPanel = new Panel();

//Aquí diseño el panel de como se mostrara en tiempo de ejecución
        nuevoPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(135, 150, 254);
        nuevoPanel.Controls.Add(labelNombre);
        nuevoPanel.Controls.Add(labelTelefono);
//Creo una variable Y. La cual inicializo en 0 y cada que inserto un panel incrementa 60
        nuevoPanel.Location = new Point(0, Y);
        nuevoPanel.Name = "panelTel" + contador;
        nuevoPanel.Size = new Size(206, 56);
        Y += 60;

//Estos son los Label que agrego dentro del panel NuevoPanel

        Label labelTelefono = new Label();
        labelTelefono.AutoSize = true;
        labelTelefono.Font = new Font("Lucida Sans", 11.25F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);
        labelTelefono.ForeColor = Color.White;
        labelTelefono.Location = new Point(21, 27);
        labelTelefono.Name = "labelTelefono" + contador;
        labelTelefono.Size = new Size(108, 17);
        labelTelefono.Text = "Numero de telefono";

        Label labelNombre = new Label();
        labelNombre.AutoSize = true;
        labelNombre.Font = new Font("Lucida Sans", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);
        labelNombre.ForeColor = Color.White;
        labelNombre.Location = new Point(8, 6);
        labelNombre.Name = "labelNombre" + contador;
        labelNombre.Size = new Size(88, 14);
        labelNombre.Text = "Nombre de la persona ";

        //Incremento contador
        contador++;

//Por ultimo el panel creado en tiempo de ejecucion lo agrego al panel en el cual aparecera
        panelPrincipal.Controls.Add(nuevoPanel);
```

El funcionamiento de esto es cuando doy click a un botón para crear el panel en tiempo de ejecución estos se van agregando hacia abajo siempre el ultimo agregado queda hasta abajo por la variable Y. El cual va incrementando de 60 en 60.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de ir agregando un panel este se posicione hasta arriba (Y = 0) mientras que el primero agregado se vaya desplazando hacia bajo quedando hasta el ultimo.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder hacer esto?

Comment: En el nuevo panel le pones siempre `Y = 0;`, pero también deberás recorrer el resto de paneles para incrementar su `Y` es decir `Y += 60;`. Antes de crear el nuevo panel haces un `foreach` de todos los controles `Panel` y le cambias la Y.

Comment: Si pensé hacerlo de esa manera, solo que hay problema, al agregar los dos primeros `Panel` funciona pero de los demás agregados ya no porque van a tener la misma posición de `Y += 60`  estos se van a estar sobre poniendo encima de los otros y siempre se estará mostrando dos `Panel` se necesita estar aguadando la posición de `Panel` creado y estarle sumando al anterior Panel para que estén bajando, Ejemplo: Tengo 4 `Panel` creados los 4 `Panel` deben de bajar para al momento de agregar otro se posicione hasta arriba `Y = 0;`   los 5 Panel tendrán la posición diferente.

Comment: No entiendo tu problema.. en el primer comentario te dijeron como hacerlo, en tu comentario no quedo nada claro tu problema...

Answer (score 2):

Como te han dicho en los comentarios, tienes que recorrer los paneles existentes para modificar la altura de los que ya hay. Para ello tienes que utilizar un `foreach`, mirando que el control que modificas sea de tipo `Panel`

```
foreach(Control p in panelPrincipal.Controls)
{
   if (p is Panel)
   {
      p.Location.Top = p.Location.Top + 60; //O de forma resumida p.Location.Top += 60;
   }
}
```

Después, creas el panel tal y como lo tienes, únicamente modificando esta linea:

```
nuevoPanel.Location = new Point(0, Y);
```

por

```
nuevoPanel.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

La variable `Y` ya no te hace falta puesto que los paneles que generes quieres que estén arriba.

Recuerda que tienes que modificar la posición de los paneles existentes **ANTES** de crear el nuevo, si no lo que te ocurrirá es que te los superpondrá todo el rato a 60px de la parte de arriba del contenedor.